# How to install backported programs?

Tags: backport, realtime

How to get backported kernel and nautilus? I'm on 10.04 and I want to use fixes which are made in 12.04. I'm being told about installing backported kernel.

On 10.04, I have some bugs which have been fixed with latest kernel and latest nautilus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the oneiric kernel is the most recent backported kernel. This can be installed with `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-backport-oneiric`.
There are no other packages which you can install, because nearly everything depends on gnome3, and lucid has only gnome2.

If you need newer packages, upgrade to precise.

Comment: no way ill upgrade to precise- everything is slow even if i put gnome-session-fallback . so im looking for way to get 10.04 to be latests updates for all programms.

Comment: one does not simply use lucid and have the updates from precise

Comment: i still would like to get updates for programms still using gnome in 10.04